# Java passing 2 dimension array to method

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing

```
public static void main{
    String [][] book = new String[100][6];

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            book[i][j] = i;
        }
    }

    arrayMethod(book);
}

public static void arrayMethod(String[][] array){
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array));
}
```

***arrayMethod method output is** [[Ljava.lang.String;@639facbc, [Ljava.lang.String;@8059dbd, [Ljava.lang.String;@28b6e768, [Ljava.lang.String;@1271ba, ....*

Problem is that in arrayMethod I can't acces 2 dimension array data, where can be problem?

Comment: to compile you have to use   book[i][j] =""+ i;

Comment: What about the signature of main method ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you want: you're pretending the (first-level) array is a `List` (of `Array`) and then printing the `toString()` of those, which looks something like `[Ljava.lang.String@pointer`. You probably want this instead:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Answer (score 2):

as Alya'a Gamal said, if you want to put an int inside an array of String you need to parse it : `book[i][j] = Integer.toString(i);`.
Then if you want to display your array, you need to run thought it, like this for example :

```
public static void arrayMethod(String[][] array){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length;i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length;j++)
                System.out.println(array[i][j]); // a stringBuilder would be better than to print inside the loop
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have one problem, passing only 1 (last) array element, all oher elements is `null`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Arrays.toString` to print 1-D string array, but you **CANNOT** use `Arrays.toString` to print the 2-D array directly.

There are 2 ways for you to print the 2D string array in console.

**Way#1 ==>**

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

**Way#2 ==>**

```
 for(String[] arr: array)
 {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I see three issues here :

(1). The signature of the main method looks odd. It would raise a compile issue.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
// Your code here
}
```

(2). In the following code :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            book[i][j] = i;
        }
    }

book[i][j] =i; // Here you are trying to insert an int in place where a String is required.
```

This will again lead to a compile time issue.

You can correct it as follows:

```
 book[i][j] = Integer.toString(i);
```

(3).

Use the following static method in the `Arrays` class to print the elements of 2D array on the console.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Hope this helps.

+1 for isolating the problem.